# How to reconnect BLE device in background after turn off and then turn on?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working on a small project related to BLE. I have a requirement that I need to re-connect the device in background after manual turn off and then off bluetooth from iPhone->Settings->Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the peripheral identifier or (UUID for < iOS 7), retrieve the peripheral, and call connect on it when the centralManager updates state to powered on.

**For iOS 7:**

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
    {
        if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
        {
            NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:savedUUID];//where savedUUID is the string version of the NSUUID you've saved somewhere

            NSArray *peripherals = [_cbCentralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[uuid]];

            for(CBPeripheral *periph in peripherals)
            {
                [_cbCentralManager connectPeripheral:periph options:nil];
            }
        }
    }
```

**For iOS 6:**

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
    {
        if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
        {
            CFUUIDRef uuid;//the cfuuidref you've previously saved
            [central retrievePeripherals:@[(id)uuid]];//now wait for the delegate callback below
        }
    }

    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
    {
        for(CBPeripheral *periph in peripherals)
        {
            [_centralManager connectPeripheral:periph options:nil];
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** these are just code snippets. You should also monitor `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff` (among others) and cancel all current peripheral connections when you get that update.